# Приведение типов TJSONObject и TJSONArray

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

На входе имеется строка с JSON-документом неопределенного типа. Возможны варианты: JSONObject, JSONArray или пустая строка не являющаяся JSON-документом. Как определить тип документа и привести его к нужному классу для дальнейшей обработки? Набросал пример, вроде бы рабочий но сам понимаю что он далек от совершенства, хотелось бы более оптимальной реализации, без повторяющихся ParseJSONValue и c приведением типов.

```
procedure TForm1.ParseJSON(JSONString: String);
var
  JSONArray: TJSONArray;
  JSONObject: TJSONObject;
begin
  // проверяем является ли входящая строка JSON-документом
  if JSONObject.Parse(BytesOf(JSONString),0)>=0 then
    begin
      if JSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONString).ClassName = 'TJSONObject' then
        begin
          JSONObject:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONString) as TJSONObject;
          {обработка JSONObject}
          FreeAndNil(JSONObject);
        end;

      if JSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONString).ClassName = 'TJSONArray' then
        begin
          JSONArray:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONString) as TJSONArray;
          {обработка JSONArray}
          FreeAndNil(JSONArray);
        end;
    end;

end;
```

Comment: Благодарю всех за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде (в вопросе), помимо двойных вызовов ParseJSONValue есть еще один недостаток - каждый вызов этого метода возвращает объект. Но вы уничтожаете только объекты, созданные при повторном вызове, что приводит к утечкам памяти.

Избавиться от обоих недостатков можно так:

```pascal
var
  JSONValue: TJSONValue;
  JSONObject: TJSONObject;
  JSONArray: TJSONArray;
begin
  JSONValue := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(str); // ParseXXX - это классовый метод, ему не нужен экземпляр класса.
  if not Assigned(JSONValue) then
    Exit; // из документации - если входящая строка
          // не является валидным JSON-документом,
          // то вернется nil
  try
    if JSONValue is TJSONObject then
      begin
        JSONObject := TJSONObject(JSONValue);
        // используем JSONObject
      end;

    if JSONValue is TJSONArray then
      begin
        JSONArray := TJSONArray(JSONValue);
        // используем JSONArray;
      end;
  finally
    JSONValue.Free; // уничтожаем именно JSONValue, а не
    // object или array, поскольку последние - тот же самый
    // объект, просто с уточненным типом.
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать примерно вот так:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  VParseResult: Integer;
  VArr: TJSONArray;
  VObj: TJSONObject;
  VJsonValue: TJSONValue;
  VJsonObject: TJSONObject;
begin
  VJsonObject := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    VParseResult := VJsonObject.Parse(BytesOf(JsonString), 0);
    if VParseResult > 0 then begin
      for I := 0 to VJsonObject.Count - 1 do begin
        VJsonValue := VJsonObject.Pairs[I].JsonValue;
        if VJsonValue is TJSONObject then begin
          VObj := VJsonValue as TJSONObject;
          // use VObj
        end else if VJsonValue is TJSONArray then begin
          VArr := VJsonValue as TJSONArray;
          // use VArr
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    VJsonObject.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Если известны имена ожидаемых полей во входящем JSON, то вместо итерирования можно запрашивать конкретное поле, и далее уже работать с ним:

```
VJsonValue := VJsonObject.GetValue('my_field');
if Assigned(VJsonValue) then begin
  // приводим VJsonValue к нужному типу (объект или массив) и работаем с ним 
end;
```